# QGIS Process Modeller Multiple Input (3.4.4)

Tags: qgis

I am trying to build a process with the process modeler.
The process is working with one shapefile via Input vectorlayer.

But in the final Version the model should do a Folder or Muliple Input. But if I Chose Folder or Multiple Input, I can't connect them to an other part of the model.

Could please anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Zio! Which tool(s) are you trying to use with multiple inputs?

Comment: You can run models as batch processes, does this suit your needs?

Comment: @Joseph the first tool I try to use is simplify (I hope thats the correct wording in english)
Erik no that doesnt' really help in my case

Comment: So this my model, And the blue arrow Shows what i want to do
https://ibb.co/zsRxXBG

Comment: @Zio - Can you explain why a batch process would not work for your case? There are only a select few tools available which take multiple files as input. What about using the **Merge vector layers** tool to combine all your vector layers (this accepts multiple input parameters) and then use the merged result as the input to your **Simplify** tool?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications, and to embed a picture of your model using the Picture button.